# Why i am unable to mock the activated route?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to mock my activated route but its throwing undefined error at get. I tried tweaking the code and stuffs but in vain. The error it shows is

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
at ViewEmployeesbyDeptComponent.call [as ngOnInit] (http://localhost:9877/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/components/departments/view-employeesby-dept/view-employeesby-dept.component.ts:19:51)

Here is my component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getId = Number(this.ar.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this.getId).subscribe({
        next:(data) => {
          this.viewEmp = data;
          
        }
      
    })
  }
```

Here is my service.ts:

```
 getEmployeesByDepartment(id: number): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.baseApiUrl + "/department/" + id + "/employee");
  }
```

Here is my spec.ts:

```
describe('ViewEmployeesbyDeptComponent', () => {
  let component: ViewEmployeesbyDeptComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ViewEmployeesbyDeptComponent>;
  let mockEmpService: DepartmentsService;
  let httpController: HttpTestingController;
  let mockActivatedRoute;

  let mockEmp: any = [{
    //dummy data
  }];

  beforeEach(async () => {

    mockActivatedRoute = {
      snapshot: { paraMap: { get: () => { return '1' } } }
    };

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ViewEmployeesbyDeptComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule, HttpClientModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: DepartmentsService, useValue: mockEmpService },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
        { provide: HttpTestingController, useValue: httpController }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    

    mockEmpService = TestBed.inject(DepartmentsService);
    httpController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ViewEmployeesbyDeptComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Should Get Employees By Department ID', () => {
   spyOn(mockEmpService, 'getEmployeesByDepartment')
   .and
   .callThrough();
   component.ngOnInit();
   expect(mockEmpService.getEmployeesByDepartment).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
   expect(component.getId).toBe(1);
   expect(component.employees).toEqual(mockEmp);
  });
});
```

Comment: typo in your mock: 'paraMap'

Comment: @desertech oh lord, all the troubles for a typo. Thank you for the help